# Issues with event created buttons not aligning as expected

Tags: vb.net-2010

new bloke having issues again.I have a button on a form which is set to create another button in it's current location, then using a timer that runs

```
    button.top = button.top + 10
```

for every tick, the design created (aka button creator) button moves down to just under the new button, and in the same alignment. Due to the size of the form I'm working on, once this has been done 3 times, the creator button is now askew, slightly to the right of the added buttons above it, rather than than in the same place, due to the controls now extending past the form size and the scrollbar becoming visible.

I've done some searching around, but so far the answers I have found haven't helped - probably more due to me not understanding correctly - and it's starting to do my head in because it should logically be so simple.

I thought I'd figured out the issue this evening when I realised that it's the previously added buttons which are moving from

```
    location.x = 100
```

to

```
    location.x = 91
```

and not the creator button changing it's habits.

Can anyone point out what is probably something so simple that I am overlooking in order to get these aligned?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using the location.x property try using LEFT property of the object...
so when you create the NEW button and set its inital position use the ThisButton.Left = Value to position it....

where ThisButton is the NAME of your button
and Value is the X location numeric value.